# Grants for Oracle User

Tags: security, oracle, permissions

How do I get a list of all security rights for a specific Oracle user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

System privileges for a user:

```
SELECT PRIVILEGE
  FROM sys.dba_sys_privs
 WHERE grantee = <theUser>
UNION
SELECT PRIVILEGE 
  FROM dba_role_privs rp JOIN role_sys_privs rsp ON (rp.granted_role = rsp.role)
 WHERE rp.grantee = <theUser>
 ORDER BY 1;
```

Direct grants to tables/views:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, select_priv, insert_priv, delete_priv, update_priv, references_priv, alter_priv, index_priv 
  FROM table_privileges
 WHERE grantee = <theUser>
 ORDER BY owner, table_name;
```

Indirect grants to tables/views:

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner, table_name, PRIVILEGE 
  FROM dba_role_privs rp JOIN role_tab_privs rtp ON (rp.granted_role = rtp.role)
 WHERE rp.grantee = <theUser>
 ORDER BY owner, table_name;
```

Comment: Most welcome! Glad to help...